# Antd DatePicker inside Form setFieldValue not working

Tags: reactjs, forms, datepicker, field, antd

I called API and setFieldValue for my DatePicker inside a Form.Item. The calender shows the wrong date. Can someone give me solutions to fix it?

Here is my code setFieldValue after call API success

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (modalId) {
      setLoading(true);
      
      holidayApi
        .getHolidayById(modalId)
        .then((res) => {
          const values = res.data.entry;         
          form.setFieldsValue({            
            start: values.start
              ? moment(new Date(values.start * 1000))
              : null,     
          });        
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          notification.open({
            message: "Something went wrong",
            placement: "topRight",
            duration: 3,
          });
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
  }, [modalId, form]);
```

And here is my code render form

```
<Form form={form} onFinish={onFinish}>
     <Form.Item label="Start" name="start" colon={false}>
          <DatePicker
               placeholder={"DD/MM/YY"}
               inputReadOnly={true}
               format={"DD/MM/YY"}
               placement="topLeft"
               style={{ width: 156 }}
          />
      </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

[image]

Comment: If you are using antd v5 then use dayjs instead of momentjs.